# how to evaluate this contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

how to evaluate $\int_0^\infty \! e^{ipx} \, \mathrm{d}x$, I know I can take the contour in the first quadrant, but why how does the integral over the arc vanish as R goes infinity, as it does not satisfy the Jordan Lemma.

Comment: Is $p$ complex?

Comment: Because if it did, then your integral would be finite for positive real $p$, which it isn't.